# How to use or work with fileshare.aio library?

Tags: django, azure, async-await, python-asyncio, azure-file-share

I have been trying to implement the [azure.storage.fileshare.aio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.aio?view=azure-python) Python SDK to upload files to my Azure File Share.
I tried using the `asyncio` class and its functions to implement the `directory_client.upload_file()` function, that seems to be not working as expected.

It will be appreciated if I get some assistance, Do's and Don'ts on the same.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are having a problem implementing a function named `upload_file`, why did you not show us your code for that function?  Why did you show us some pseudocode for a function named `some_other_func` even though the rest of your code doesn't reference it?  You need to improve the question if you expect to get any useful help.

Comment: Hey @PaulCornelius, for your information, I have given the implementation of `upload_file` function inside the `save()` function. And this `upload_file` function is one from Azure's Python SDK.  Kindly, go through the code once again. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but you did not.  What's in the `save` function is a _call_ to `upload_file`, not an "implementation."  Implementations have to use the "def" keyword.  This is standard computer science terminology.  If `upload_file` is already implemented in an imported package, I don't really understand your problem.  Could you please re-word your question?  Please include an explanation of "control directly jumps to the return statement".  It isn't clear what you are expecting the code to do before the `return Response.send_response` line.

Comment: @AvjVaibhav Provide your expected result and screenshot. Are you trying to upload a local file to Azure files share using the `azure.storage.fileshare.aio` library?

Comment: @AvjVaibhav I am able to upload the files from the local path to the Azure service using    ` azure.storage.fileshare.aio`

Comment: @Venkatesan Hey, I am actually trying to upload a file which i receive through HTTP request, which is handled by Django Function based views. 

As a standalone script to upload a file from local to Azure using `aio` package is working fine for me,  as well.

Comment: with Azure function?

Comment: @Sampath Yes with azure's `upload_file()` function

Comment: @Sampath I don't think we both are in same page.

Comment: @AvjVaibhav refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76884624/how-to-download-a-file-from-azure-fileshare-with-python) and [reference](https://vivekyadavofficial.medium.com/upload-file-to-azure-blob-storage-in-django-python-696c995d2a25#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20simple%20article%20to%20demonstrate%20file,Project.%20Obtain%20access%20keys%20to%20your%20Azure%20Storage.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-file-share-readme?view=azure-python#uploading-a-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created storage account in azure portal. A new file share has been added to my storage account.
Check like below:

[image]

**Code:**

- `azure.storage.fileshare.aio` package has to be installed.

```
async def upload_file_to_share():
    try:
        # Initialize the ShareServiceClient asynchronously
        async with ShareServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string) as service_client:
            # Get a reference to the file share
            async with service_client.get_share_client(share_name) as share_client:
                # Get a reference to the file
                async with share_client.get_file_client(file_path) as file_client:
                    # Open the local file for reading in binary mode
                    with open(local_file_path, "rb") as local_file:
                        # Upload the file to Azure File Share asynchronously
                        await file_client.upload_file(local_file)

        print(f"File '{file_path}' uploaded successfully to Azure File Share.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

async def main():
    await upload_file_to_share()
```

- The above code is Executed Successfully in my environment as shown in below:

[image]

After it was done, I am able to Upload the files Successfully into my storage account as shown in below:

**Output:**

[image]